# Showing that the magnitude of the difference of two vectors is larger than the difference of it's vector magnitudes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Long title. I have to prove (the problem itself suggests using Pythagorean theorem) the following inequality:

> $$\|u\|-\|v\| \le \|u-v\| $$

Vector magnitudes... How do you prove this in an eloquent fashion?

*Edited out dot product, translating algebra is really hit or miss sometimes.*

Comment: The problem as stated doesn't involve any dot products.

Comment: You can be even stricter and write it as $\left||u|-|v|\right| \le |u-v|$.  This is known as the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: @Bye_World Alright fixed that... I think?

Comment: @FemtoComm No.  Sorry, it's not rendering well.  I meant the absolute value of the norm of u minus the norm of v: $\operatorname{abs}(\|u\|-\|v\|) = {\large |}\|u\|-\|v\|{\large |}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's prove something else instead.  Let's prove ${\big |}\|u\|-\|v\|{\big |} \le \|u-v\|$.

Square the LHS to get: $(\|u\|-\|v\|)^2 = \|u\|^2-2\|u\|\|v\|+\|v\|^2$.

Then we know from the Cauchy inequality that $(\|u\|-\|v\|)^2 = \|u\|^2-2\|u\|\|v\|+\|v\|^2 \le \|u\|^2-2(u\cdot v)+\|v\|^2 =\|u-v\|^2$

Take the square root of both sides to get ${\big |}\|u\|-\|v\|{\big |} \le \|u-v\|$.

Because $a\le |a|$ for all $a\in \Bbb R$, we have $\|u\|-\|v\| \le {\big |}\|u\|-\|v\|{\big |} \le \|u-v\|$.  $\ \ \ \square$

Thus by proving this stricter inequality, we get yours back for free.

Comment: I had gotten that far, I didn't think of squaring both sides. Now I did it looks so clear. One side is always positive thus ending my struggle.

Comment: Note that if you're trying to prove the identity in your question as written, your final line should look like "Therefore $\|u\|-\|v\| \le {\big |}\|u\|-\|v\|{\big |} \le \|u-v\|$

Comment: But-But...
$$
\|u\|-\|v\| \le\|u-v\|
$$
$$
\{\sqrt{u^2}-\sqrt{v^2}\}^2\le\{\sqrt{(u^2-2uv+v^2}\}^2
$$
$$
u^2-2uv+v^2\le|u^2-2uv+v^2|\tag{yes/no/maybeso?}
$$

Comment: @FemtoComm See my answer now.

Comment: If you haven't gotten to the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, this identity can also be proven with the Pythagorean theorem or the regular triangle inequality.  So the theorems you have at your disposal are really what dictate how this should be proven.

Comment: Regardless of whether I learned the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I see what you did there. Seeing others execute problems and list their reasoning works wonders for me. PS. I have learned the CS inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the triangle inequality

$|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$

setting $x = v$ and $y = u-v$.