# How to show that L2 norm is Lipschitz if the input domain is bounded?

Tags: lipschitz-functions

I guess that $||w||_2^2$ is 2B Lipschitz when $||w||<B$.
That's because the gradient $||w||_2^2$ is $2w$ and $w$ is bounded, but I can't show my claim according to the definition of the Lipschitzness. Can anybody help me formally prove my claim?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What space are you working in? Is this just $\Bbb{R}^n$, with the Euclidean norm? Is it a Hilbert space? Or is it something more general? Are the scalars real? Complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the norm of an element v, as $\left\|v \right\|=sup\frac{<v,x>}{\left\|x \right\|}$ then the Lipschitz continuity follows from the inequality sup(f(x)+g(x))$\leq $supf(x)+supg(x), which implies (set f+g=h)  , suph(x)-supf(x) $\leq$ sup(h(x)-f(x)).  Since $sup\frac{<v,x>}{\left\|x \right\|}-sup\frac{<w,x>}{\left\|x \right\|}\leq sup\frac{<v-w,x>}{\left\| x\right\|}=\left\|v-w \right\|$. Likewise the l.h.s is $\geq   -\left\|v-w \right\|$ and hence $\left|\left\|v \right\|-\left\| w\right\| \right|\leq \left\|v-w \right\|$ (1). Thus, with the standard definition of a norm of an element of the dual space, Lipschitz continuity always holds.In the case of a finite dimensional space and a Euclidean norm, the definition $\left\|v \right\|=\sqrt{v_{1}^{2}+...v_{n}^{2}}$ coincides with $\left\|v \right\|=sup\frac{<v,x>}{\left\|x \right\|}$ and again the L-continuity  holds! If you are interested in L-continuity of the square of the norm then by (1) above, $\left|\left\|v \right\|^{2}-\left\| w\right\|^{2} \right|\leq \left\|v-w \right\|\left|\left\| v\right\|+\left\|w \right\| \right|$ which implies that the square of the norm is L-continuous on bounded sets.

Comment: To the readers: A simpler proof of inequality (1) is available: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068156/showing-that-the-magnitude-of-the-difference-of-two-vectors-is-larger-than-the-d